# jQuery animate. How to set top and left in auto

Tags: jquery, css

I have some block with style:

```
#block{
    position: absolute;
    width: 290px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #a71;
    right: 90px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

I change its properties as follows:

```
$('#block').animate({
        height: '545px',
        width: '680px',
        left: '50%',
        top: '50%',
        marginTop: '-282.5px',
        marginLeft: '-350px'
    }, 1000);
```

But how am I going to return the block to its initial state?
This code does not work:

```
$('#block').animate({
        top: 'auto',
        left:'auto',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        height: '200px',
        width: '290px',
        marginTop: '-5px',
        right: '90px'       
    }, 1500);
```

It works like this, but without animation:

```
$('#block').css({
        'top': 'auto',
        'left':'auto',
        'marginLeft': 'auto',
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

"auto" won't have effect after you set it to some value (ie 50%). 
You should get the top and left values after rendering is complete and before you start the animation. Experiment with `$('#block').offset()` smt. like:

```
$(function() {
  var offset = $('#block').offset();

  $('.some-btn').click(function() {
    $('#block').animate({
      height: '545px',
      width: '680px',
      left: '50%',
      top: '50%',
      marginTop: '-282.5px',
      marginLeft: '-350px'
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('.some-other-btn').click(function() {
    $('#block').css({
      'top': offset.top,
      'left':offset.left,
      'marginLeft': 'auto',
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate to `auto` so that code will never work

You'd be better served by setting the `top`, `left` and `margin-left` positions before animating in variables. Then when you want to animate back, you can give the actual initial values rather than just `auto`

To animate there...

```
var originalTop = $('#block').css('top');
var originalLeft = $('#block').css('left');
var originalMarginLeft = $('#block').css('margin-left');

// Animate away from initial state...
$('#block').animate({
    height: '545px',
    width: '680px',
    left: '50%',
    top: '50%',
    marginTop: '-282.5px',
    marginLeft: '-350px'
}, 1000);

// Animate back to initial state...
$('#block').animate({
    top: originalTop,
    left: originalLeft,
    marginLeft: originalMarginLeft,
    height: '200px',
    width: '290px',
    marginTop: '-5px',
    right: '90px'       
}, 1500);
```

Comment: If I do so, then left equals an any number, but left in the initial state is not set

Answer (score 0):

Same approach here, auto just wont work. You can store your values on some variables and use them later on if resize is not a problem.

Im not sure, but maybe you can create a hidden element below #block and use its position when you animate back.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It work like this:

```
$('#block').animate({
        height: '545px',
        width: '680px',
        **right:** '50%',
        top: '50%',
        marginTop: '-282.5px',
        **marginRight:** '-350px'
    }, 1000);
```

and

```
$('#block').animate({
        marginRight: '0px',
        top: curTop,
        height: '200px',
        width: '290px',
        marginTop: '-5px',
        right: '90px'       
    }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JS instead of jQuery to reset the CSS state when animation completed.

Try this:

```
$('#block').animate({
    top: 'auto',
    left:'auto',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    height: '200px',
    width: '290px',
    marginTop: '-5px',
    right: '90px'       
    }, 1500,function(){
    document.getElementById("block").style.left = 'auto';
});
```